# Find last iteration of foreach loop in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In blade template i use last() method to find last iteration of foreach loop:

```
@foreach ($colors as $k => $v)
   <option value={!! $v->id !!} {{ $colors->last()->id==$v->id ? 'selected':'' }} > {!! $v->name !!} </option>
@endforeach
```

Is it ok? Perhaps there is a Laravel-style way to do the same?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

As for Laravel 5.3+, you can use the [$loop](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable) variable

```
$loop->last

@foreach ($colors as $k => $v)
     @if($loop->last)
         // at last loop, code here
     @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You might wanna correct the if-condition It should have parentheses instead of double curly-braces :)

Comment: @andersevenrud double curly-braces are not necessary for if conditions, which works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

What you do is absolutely fine if you want to obtain instance of the last item in the collection.

Additionally, in Laravel 5.3 you can use `$loop` variable, which allows you to get boolean for last iteration `$loop->last` or to obtain current iteration index `$loop->iteration`, total number of records `$loop->count` and a few more [The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable)

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

    {{ $post->title }} ({{ $loop->iteration }} of {{ $loop->count }})   

@endforeach
```

Comment: +1 Also, I think it's worth mentioning the `$loop->last` bit itself, which solves the main issue of this question.

Answer (score 3):

if `$colors` is a `Collection`, `$colors->last()` and `end($colors)` both works

Answer (score 3):

```
@foreach ($colors as $v)
    <option value={!! $v->id !!} {!!($v == end($colors)) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' !!} > {!! $v->name !!} </option>
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach ($colors as $v)
    <option value={!! $v->id !!} {{($v == end($colors)) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} > {!! $v->name !!} </option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if that last method is working but if not, try this:

```
@foreach ($colors as $v)
<option value={!! $v->id !!} @if($v == end($colors)) 'selected' @endif > {!! $v->name !!} </option>
@endforeach
```