# Display comma and space properly in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to display tags on a page and the trick is that I do not want to show comma after the last tag.

So, I have this:

```
@foreach($tag as $t)
   <a href="/search?q={{$t}}" class="tags">{{$loop->first ? '' : ', '}} {{$t}}</a>
@endforeach
```

And I want to have this:

`A, B, C, D`

But instead, I get this:

`A , B , C , D`

There is extra space between item and comma...

Comment: Ahm http://stackoverflow.com/a/41142658/4916265

Comment: Note: The comma should not be a part of the link, better place it after `</a>,`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check if the loop is on the last item or not, and if not, append a comma and a space (instead of prepending a comma and a space).

For example:

```
@foreach($tag as $t)
   <a href="/search?q={{$t}}" class="tags">{{$t}}{{$loop->last ? '' : ', '}}</a>
@endforeach
```

The reason you were getting double spaces is because you were echoing out a space in PHP and also putting a space between your two curly braces.

Update: Although your answer would also work, it's a matter of preference. The original reason you had an extra space between the letter and comma was due to spacing between the curly brace variables.

Comment: he is asking about why there is extra space !!

Comment: That's it. Perfect!

Comment: @Mohammad Alabed Because he adds extar space at `', '` and `}} {{`, and thats not noted by him 8-[

Comment: Refresh my answer! :)

Comment: @harunB10 While this will work, I just want to point out that the original extra space is due to the spaces you have before the opening `<a>` tag. This solution works because you are guaranteeing the comma comes after the tag without spaces. Your previous code would work if you removed all the spaces before your opening `<a>` tag.

Comment: @patricus The extra spaces are coming from between the curly braces -- since the CSV is contained within the link, he's showing spaces between A and the comma, etc. I've updated my answer because your last point is correct.

Comment: @HalfCrazed The spaces between the curly braces didn't have anything to do with it. That just added an extra space after the comma, and multiple spaces after the comma are just condensed down to one space on display. The issue the OP was having was there was an extra space after the tag and before the comma. This extra space due to the OP indenting their code. While it makes the code a little prettier, it is actually outputting whitespace, and that whitespace happened to be between the last comma and the next printed tag.

Comment: @patricus Yes, that is working as well. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Gotcha, I see what you mean now. :D