# How to remove the space before a comma in laravel blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
@foreach($opt as $key => $o)
   @if($o == 1)A @endif
   @if($o == 2)B @endif
   @if($key+1 != count($opt)), @endif
@endforeach
```

How can i show the expected output A, B, C ?

```
//Current Output       A , B , C        
//Expected Output      A, B, C
```

Comment: Related? [Display comma and space properly in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612815/display-comma-and-space-properly-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: @FirstOne Kinda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
@foreach($opt as $key => $o)
    {{ $o == 1 ? 'A' : '' }}{{ $o == 2 ? 'B' : '' }}@if($key+1 != count($opt)), @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Zidance try to combine like I've shown. But I guess it's not readable, so you may want to prepare the output before passing it to the template or something.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a total pain to keep the blade syntax readable, so I duplicate the word prior to the comma in the if/else statement.

Desired output:

```
<p>Some text goes here, with this conditional text</p>
```

Blade structure

```
<p>Some text goes
    @if($condition)
        here, with this conditional text
    @else
        here
    @endif
</p>
```