# How to get the last item of for loop

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, foreach, laravel-5.8

So in Laravel, when we use `foreach` loop, we can simply say:

```
@foreach ($colors as $k => $v)
     @if($loop->last)
         // at last loop, code here
     @endif
@endforeach
```

To get the last item of the loop.

But what if we use `for` loop like this:

```
@for($y=0;$y<=count($paths)-1;$y++)

   // if last item of the loop, do something here
@endfor
```

So how I define the last item of `for` loop just like `foreach` loop?

Comment: `$y === count ($paths) - 1` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find last iteration of foreach loop in laravel blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976321/find-last-iteration-of-foreach-loop-in-laravel-blade)

Comment: This might be useful for you. PHP has a builtin function called `end()`. you can use it to find the last element of an array. But it can not be used inside the element's for loop. Ex: `end($paths);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array functions just like `end()` and/or `current()` and/or ect .
for ex :

```
foreach ($colors as $k => $v) {
    if($v == end($colors)) {
     // at last loop, code here
    }
}
```

also can try to keep iterates number and check if is it the last one or not, but the first solution has better performance and keeps your code cleaner.

```
$iterateNumber = 0;
foreach ($colors as $k => $v) {
    $iterateNumber++ ; 
    if($iterateNumber == count($colors)) {
     // at last loop, code here
    }
}
```

Comment: he asked about for, not foreach. bad answer..